# How to download android source at source-android.frandroid.com

Tags: android, macos

How to download all files at http://source-android.frandroid.com? I am using macos.

Comment: You get get it from official source download: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar source [here](https://github.com/android/) where I can check it out with GIT

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?
Just use the official tools to download from the official repository:
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Or at least download an archive from their github mirror. Find the package you want to get the source and click on the download as zip button, exemple for plateform_frameworks_base: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base